# I want to use an object inside a json array as search criteria in mysql8

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have a JSON array in a table of MySQL database such as

```json
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": "job"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": "2022-05-11 18:00:00"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "value": 100
  }
]
```

how can i search for the criteria `"key=3 and value >= 100"` ?

Comment: Parse array to separate values and use as a condition.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What's your exact aim? eg. Do you want to bring only the last object of the array or whole array if one object matches the criteria ?